# Weight colors not affecting strength of bones!

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have made a model and I am now rigging it but when I change the weights of different faces it always acts like it is at 100% strength anyway. This is really annoying!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weight painting (or assigning) makes comparison between at least two assignement, with an automatic normalization of values:
take two vertices (let we call them A and B) and two bones (boneC and boneD):

if you assign to the boneC vertex group a weight for A 1.0 and for B 0.5, and to the boneD vertex group no weights, then you move the boneC in pose mode, A and B will move exactly with it.

In the same situation let's now assign a weight of 1.0 for both A and B to the boneD vertex group: now move the bone C, 4 BlenderUnits toward left: A will move 2 BU left, while B will move 1.33333 BU only.

Consider that, in case of single wieght assignement, even a value of 0.0001 is infinitely greater than 0.0, so it will be treated in the same way as a 1.0 assignement.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't really understand what you meant at first but after I played around with it for a bit I figured it out. =D